# Can I dial a whatsapp number from a sip account?

Tags: sip, voip, whatsapp

Is it possible to call a whatsapp contact from other than whatsapp, say for example I have a sip provider. Can I use it to call a whatsapp number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not, as far as I can tell, any directly supported way to do this.   The whole Whatsapp paradigm is mobile-phone-centric to the extent that even tablets (running the same OS) won't work and the Chrome web app requires you to *use your phone to authenticate it* by scanning a QR code.

The closest I have been able to find is the yowsup2 library which has some tools that could probably be used to script up a SIP-to-Whatsapp bridge running on a Linux server.  That would be IM text only though, since I don't think that library supports voice calls.

A PC running the Android development environment and Freeswitch/Asterix would have all the pieces you need to build a bridge for voice calls, but it would be a real project to put all that together.

If you can figure out a way to make Bluetooth-initiated calls go through Whatsapp (a big "if"), then you can accomplish a similar result with one of those BT-to-analog line adapters and an ordinary phone.

In Skype-land, this can be done by forwarding calls to a PSTN number (with the concomitant charges per-minute).  I am not aware of Whatsapp having that feature.

For a while, it was possible to bridge Google Voice to SIP (when they inherited SIP subscribers from Gizmo5), and then they shut it down.  So if the Goog takes *working SIP interoperation and shuts it down*, I wouldn't plan on any of the walls coming down around the Whatsapp garden anytime soon.  If you want SIP you are on your own.